# Sort an object literal on its attribute value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, alasql

Below is my input, I would be looping through each of this element and sending each element to another function.

```
 distinctParameterList  =  [{
        careerGroupLevel: 'Analyst',
        careerGroupCode: 130,
        m06: 83,
        m05: 82,
        m08: 85,
        fymcl: 'FY18|PromotionsOut|AN-10000100:CL 2',
        m07: 84,
        m09: 86,
        intersectionId: '54697113|India|520|N'
    },
     {
        careerGroupLevel: 'Analyst',
        careerGroupCode: 130,
        m06: 95,
        m05: 94,
        m08: 97,
        fymcl: 'FY18|PromotionsOut|AN-10000110:CL 2',
        m07: 96,
        m09: 98,
        intersectionId: '54697113|India|520|N'
    },
     {
        careerGroupLevel: 'Analyst',
        careerGroupCode: 130,
        m06: 22,
        m05: 21,
        m08: 24,
        fymcl: 'FY17|PromotionsOut|AN-10000100:CL 2',
        m07: 23,
        m09: 25,
        intersectionId: '54697113|India|520|N'
    },
     {
        careerGroupLevel: 'Analyst',
        careerGroupCode: 130,
        m06: 42,
        m05: 41,
        m08: 44,
        fymcl: 'FY17|PromotionsOut|AN-10000110:CL 4',
        m07: 43,
        m09: 45,
        intersectionId: '54697113|India|520|N'
    }]
```

I am also calculating a value "calcCareerId " below :

```
let calcCareerId = fymclData.split("-")[1].split(":")[0];
```

Now i want to sort this structure on the basis of the "calcCareerId " value in fymcl attribute, so that i can get all the "10000100" values first and then "10000110".

Comment: That is a JavaScript object literal.  JSON is a `string`.

Comment: sorry, let me make the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the function:

```js
let calcCareerId = fymclData => fymclData.split("-")[1].split(":")[0];
```

You can use [`lodash`'s `sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#sortBy) function to sort in lexicographically ascending order. If you want descending order, just call `.reverse` on the result.

```js
const result = _.sortBy(distinctParameterList, ({fymcl}) => calcCareerId(fymcl));
```

or use the native `sort`:

```js
const result = distinctParameterList.sort((a, b) => {
  const valueA = calcCareerId(a.fymcl);
  const valueB = calcCareerId(b.fymcl);
  return (valueA === valueB) ? 0 : (valueA < valueB ? 1 : -1)
})
```

Note that the native `sort` mutates the array and is not stable.

Comment: Why resort to a library instead of using native `Array.prototype.sort()`?

Comment: But "calcCareerId" is only available when iam looping through the array. But the requirement is that before triggerring that loop, i need the array sorted by "10000100" etc i.e. the "fymcl" attribute value

Comment: @Rishabh Then define `calcCareerId` at the same level as `distinctParameterList`.

Comment: but calcCareerId can only be calculated when i loop in through each element of this array and then locate the fymcl attribute and then split it.

Comment: lets not confuse with calcCareerId. What i need is the array should be sorted on the basis of the value in fymcl attribute

Comment: const result = distList.sort((a, b) => {
  const valueA = (a.fymcl.split("-")[1].split(":")[0]);
  const valueB = (b.fymcl.split("-")[1].split(":")[0]);
  return (valueA === valueB) ? 0 : (valueA < valueB ? 1 : -1)
})      // this is now sorting

Comment: is there a way to use sort in a callback ?